# Trying To Export Animation Actions With Constraints Into Unreal Engine Via FBX

Tags: animation, export, baking, constraints, unreal-engine

[image: The Two Animations]So I currently have 2 separate actions for 2 Different Rigs, one for my main FPS armature, and one for the weapon. The weapon has a constraint which follows the palm, however, when I attempt to bake the animations together The Animation plays incorrectly and the weapon gets stuck in mid-air ignoring the previous constraints (even with Visual Keying applied.) Attempting to export these actions separately into Unreal also does not work due to the constraints not existing once I export these actions separately.

Here is the blend file
[image]

Comment: If you disable "All Actions" and "NLA Strips" in the FBX exporter window everything will be baked what you see in the animation. This always worked for me, but with this method you can export only one action per file. Of course you don't have to export the model everytime, so the files won't be large.